# Вызвать метод перед закрытием контекста spring

Tags: java, spring

Мне нужно выполнить код ПЕРЕД закрытием контекста спринга.
Метод с аннотацией @Predestroy вызывается уже ПОСЛЕ закрытия контекста  , и я получаю ошибку: The ApplicationContext is closed and the ConnectionFactory can no longer create connections.

Answer (score 2):

Используй слушатель событий. Описан [здесь](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events). Тебе надо слушать событие [ContextClosedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextClosedEvent.html). Простейший пример ниже:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component


@Component
public class MyClosedEventHandler 
   implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>{

   public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEventevent) {
     //здесь твоя обработка
   }
}
```

Comment: > ContextClosedEvent - Published when the ApplicationContext is closed - т.е. событие вызывается опять же ПОСЛЕ закрытия контекста

Comment: Какую задачу тебе требуется решить? Возможно тебе следует просто использовать отслеживание жизненного цикла конкретного бина. В таком случае можно посмотреть в сторону [DisposableBean](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.3.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html)